# C++ copy a vector structure, but with different objects

Tags: c++, vector

I've got a vector of `std::string` that represents the structure of another vector of object pointers. I would like to generate this vector of object pointers, where if there are two of the same objects, the pointer in the vector is also the same.

Don't know what I meant just there? let me give you an example. Let's say I have a `std::vector` of `std::string`:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
names.push_back(std::string("A"));
names.push_back(std::string("A"));
names.push_back(std::string("B"));
names.push_back(std::string("C"));
names.push_back(std::string("A"));
```

Now let's say these names (`A`, `B` and `C`) represent three different instances of an `Object`:

```
Object* ptr_A = new Object(1); // A
Object* ptr_B = new Object(2); // B
Object* ptr_C = new Object(3); // C
```

I would now like to generate the vector that holds pointers to the `Object`, in the same order as in the vector `names`:

```
std::vector<Object*> objects;
objects.push_back(ptr_A);
objects.push_back(ptr_A);
objects.push_back(ptr_B);
objects.push_back(ptr_C);
objects.push_back(ptr_A);
```

so that when two names are the same, the pointers are the same also.

How would I efficiently do this? Note that I would like the objects to be dynamically allocated inside the function that does this, so that the vector can be used later on.

I will be using this to read the objects from a file based on a name, but I want to prevent making multiple objects that are basically the same.

Since this is homework I cannot use C++11 yet.

Comment: sounds like you want a `std::map<std::string, Object*>`?

Comment: As for how to answer what you actually asked, how is the program to know that `ptr_A` is represented by "A"?  The runtime knows of no correlation.  It would have to be hardcoded by you.

Comment: Judging by your edit: Dont' use vectors at all, just use a `map` from the start.  Waay easier and faster.

Comment: the construction of the object would be based on the name in the string vector (reading the object with exactly thaat name from file).

Comment: you mean multimap right?

Comment: No, since each name only has one `Object*`, you just need a normal map.

Comment: or ... vector<pair<string,unique_ptr<Object>>> vect; Jus' Say'n

Comment: @johnathon: That's more complicated to use than a map would be.  Also, the pointers _seem_ like they might be owned elsewhere, making `unique_ptr` a (potentially) bad idea here.  (Also, he said no C++11 in a comment)

Comment: @Mooing Duck , just trolling  :) , did not notice the "no c++11" lol, and more complicated to use ... depends on perspective, as in vec.first, and vec.second ... first is always the string, second is the pointer, and if confusion arises from that.. well.. Typedef ;) , *sighs* I cant wait until a fully compliant (c++11) compiler comes to my platform.

Comment: @johnathon: The "no C++11" was added after your comment, makes it easy to miss.  By "harder to use" I meant: find the `.second`, where `.first == mystring`.  That's trickier with a vector than a map.  (It's only a line or two, but still trickier)

Comment: @MooingDuck ah... at least i don't feel so bad now!

Comment: haha, with school I mean college. This isn't really homework you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This generates a `lookup` object that maps the names to allocated objects, and then fills the vector `objects` with the values based off the values in `names`.  [Simple.](http://ideone.com/5oxuG)

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Object*>::iterator iterator;
typedef std::pair<std::string, Object*> value_type;
std::map<std::string, Object*> lookup;  //or maybe unordered_map
lookup.insert(value_type("A", ptr_A));
lookup.insert(value_type("B", ptr_B));
lookup.insert(value_type("C", ptr_C));

for(int i=0; i<names.size(); ++i) {
    iterator iter = lookup.find(names[i]);
    if (iter == lookup.end())
         throw std::runtime_error("invalid name in file");
    objects.push_back(iter->second);
}
```

If you want to generate the names and objects from the file, you can do something like this to create the names, objects, and the mapping between them all at once.  I assume that you will have to do other stuff as well, I don't know your file format.

```
std::string newname;
std::map<std::string, Object*> lookup;  //or maybe unordered_map
while(myfile >> newname)
    lookup[newname] = new Object(newname);
```

Comment: how would you do it with dynamically allocated objects that use the `name` in the constructor? e.g `new Object("A")`

Comment: @romeovs: What, like `lookup.push_back(value_type("A", new Object("A")));`?

Comment: Preferably `lookup.push_back(value_type("A", unique_ptr<Object>( new Object("A") )));`

Comment: @Prætorian: He already said he doesn't have C++0x, I'm going to assume no boost as well since they always do.

Comment: I have got c++0x, but the guys at school don't... Why would a `unique_ptr` be preferrable? @MooingDuck what I meant was that I would like to generate the lookup table from the file as well. It is unknown what number of objects there are and what their names are.

Comment: @romeovs: `unique_ptr` prevents all sorts of mistakes, like double-deletes, forgetting to delete, making accidental copies, and more.  Also, I added loading code to the answer.

Comment: I don't need the pointers outside the object the vector is used in. Yet I need to be able to delete the vector of `Object*` at the end of the day no? This is impossible with raw pointers, since you can only delete an object once as far as I know. I still don't see how unique_ptr would help me since I would like more than one ptr to the object in the vector.

Comment: @romeovs: we meant putting `unique_ptr` in the `lookup` map, assuming it remains in scope longer than `objects`.  Otherwise, you could use `shared_ptr`, which can have multiple pointers to a single object, but they're slower.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `std::vector`, use a `std::map` containing keys of `std::string` and values of `Object*`

`std::map<std::string, Object*>`

No two identical keys may be inserted into the map. If an insert is attempted that matches a previous key the original key-value is returned. When a key is requested, the same pointer is returned.